# Sharepoint list date format

Tags: sharepoint, caml

The date format for sharepoint lists is : M/D/YYYY
I have to columns in the splist: start_time and end_time, and I have to write a query where I get those fields where "todays"date is greater or equal than start_time and less than or equal than end_time. Of course I also have hours:minutes in my columns. The problem I have is that I found out that CAML date format is: yyyy/mm/ddThrs:min:ssZ. I know about the  tag to get todays date but how do I change that date format from the fields so the comparison in the query succeeds?

This is a portion of the code:

```
query.Append("<FieldRef Name = 'Start_Time'");
query.Append("/>");
query.Append("<Value Type ='DateTime'IncludeTimeValue='True'>");
query.Append("<Today/>");
query.Append("</Value>");
```

The comparison will fail since the splist date format is not in CAML date format

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<Where>
  <And>
     <Geq>
        <FieldRef Name='start_time' />
        <Value Type='DateTime'><Now /></Value>
     </Geq>
     <Leq>
        <FieldRef Name='end_time' />
        <Value Type='DateTime'><Now /></Value>
     </Leq>
  </And>
</Where>
```

As long `start_time` and `end_time` are actually of type Date and not Text, a query like this should work. Regardless of how the dates are displayed on the screen, dates will use the ISO8601 format in CAML.

Note, the above CAML was build with the help of the [U2U CAML Query Builder](http://www.u2u.be/res/tools/camlquerybuilder.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You really should check out linq for sharepoint. This will allow you use CAML query very easily and SPMetal can help you create a date entity similar to your date your using within your code.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/SP2010DevTrainingCourse_AccessingSharePointListData)

[Here](http://www.zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2010-getting-started-with-linq-to-sharepoint-in-sharepoint-2010)

Comment: we are using sp2007 the links u gave me seem to only talk about sp2010. Is there a way to change the date format in the SPLIST itself to the CAML date format, in that way my query should work as it is

Comment: Did you try to run SPMetal to your sharepoint site ? Am pretty sure it works on 2007 too. The other simplest solution would be to list those dates as a string in what ever format you want. You'll have to override each webparts to parse your strings to date object correctly tho.

Comment: does the <today/> already has the correct date format for CAML?